# Event is not defined inside method

Tags: javascript, dom-events

What is the problem in the following object:

```
var events = {
    targetElem: function(e) {
        var eve = (e) ? e : window.event;
        if (eve.target)
            alert(eve.target);
        else
            alert(eve.srcElement);
    }
};
```

Always shows me error message:

> ReferenceError: e is undefined

Comment: Can't reproduce, we need more code.

Comment: How are you calling the `targetElem` method?

Comment: @Steve: yes, `document.onclick = function() {events.targetElem();};`

Comment: @Felix Kling: when put e to targetElem as `events.targetElem(e);` show me another error  `e is not defined`.

Comment: Are you adding the "e" twice, as in the answer below?

Comment: mr @epascarello answer is the right.

Comment: Yes, his answer is correct.  But why are you not just doing: `document.onclick = events.targetElem;`? Why wrap the function inside an anonymous function?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem has nothing to do with the code you orginally posted, it has to do with the event handler in the comment you left.

```
document.onclick = function() {events.targetElem(e);};
                                                 ^
                                                 |
                                        e is not defined anywhere
```

It should be

```
document.onclick = function(e) {events.targetElem(e);};
                            ^
                            |
                        missing e
```

Answer (score 0):

If this function is being hooked up properly to an event for an element (onclick, onkeydown, onmousemove, etc), then e should be defined.

Calling events.targetElem() yourself will cause e to have the value of undefined, but you shouldn't get a ReferenceError.

Are you sure that error is happening within this function? Try putting this line at the top of your script:
"use strict";

It will warn you about silly syntax problems you might be having. (and they may be causing this jankiness)